# How can i remember data given by user

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to write a code which would be remember name given by user and on next visit will welcome him with this given name. I don't really understand cookies and session yet so I would be thankful for any help. I wrote something like this:

File: 1.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<html>
<form action="2.php" method="post">
  Name:<input type="text" name="name"/></br>
  <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
</html>
<?php
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  setcookie('name',$name,time()+3600*24);
  $_SESSION['name']=$name;
?>
```

File: 2.php

```
//2.php
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_COOKIE['name']))
    echo "Hello".$_SESSION['name'];
  else
    echo "Cookie doesnt exist";
?>
```

Comment: A session will expire when the browser is closed and cookie will stay alive until it meets it's expiry date (or you can force it to expire).

Comment: @Kitson88 is it right ?? little bit more clear. A cookie is a bit of data stored by the browser.
A session is a collection of data stored on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, `1.php` is just used for submitting to 2.php so no PHP code is being used.

**1.php**

```
<html>
<form action="2.php" method="post">
 Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
</html>
```

I've shown both instances of this below on how to set a cookie and session. You can refresh just `2.php` and the cookie output should still show the value of `$_COOKIE['name']`.

**2.php**

```
 <?php

session_start();


if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['name'];

    setcookie('name',$_SESSION['username'],time()+3600*24);

}


//Session Value will show in first instance
echo "Session Name: " . $_SESSION['username'] . "<br>";


//Cookie Value will not how until you refresh page
echo "Cookie Name: "  . $_COOKIE['name'] . "<br>";


?>
```

*Edit: Variables will not be overwritten when the page is refreshed.*

Comment: In first visit it shows only session name, in second only cookie name and in third nothing. I want to see $name after every refresh of the site

Comment: `2.php` is only used to set the Session and/or the Cookie. That's my fault for not fully explaining but if you keep refreshing `2.php`, you will keep re-assigning your Session and Cookie variables to null. I'll update my code now to avoid this so it will only update the Session or Cookie if the `$_POST[name]` is set